# when i change the encryption key i get error in line "while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)"

Tags: c#, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I make a desktop application wpf and i need to encrypt some files(images,audio),i found this solution but it works just with the encryptionkey provided.so when i try to change the encryption key ,the encryption works well but on the decryption i got this error "le remplissage n'est pas valide et ne peut pas supprimé"

```
    public void Encrypt(string inputFilePath, string outputfilePath)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsOutput, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        int data;
                        while ((data = fsInput.ReadByte()) != -1)
                        {
                            cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
                        }
                        cs.Close();
                        fsInput.Close();
                    }
                    fsOutput.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }    

    public void Decrypt(string inputFilePath, string outputfilePath)
    {
        string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
        using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
        {
            Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });
            encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
            encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
            using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsInput, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        int data;
                        while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                        {
                            fsOutput.WriteByte((byte)data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So what is the error message in *english*?

Comment: the error in english : The fill is invalid and can not be deleted and it select the line "while ((data = fsInput.ReadByte()) != -1)"

Comment: What have you done to find the error?

Comment: i changed the encryption key

Comment: Have you changed the encryption key in **both** methods?

Answer (score 1):

That error in English is "the padding is invalid and cannot be removed". It indicates that either the key or the (end of the ciphertext) has changed. It is exactly the error you should be expecting when the encryption key is not the same as the decryption key (or, in your case, if the password, salt or iteration count are incorrect).

The bad thing about CBC encryption / decryption is that you may *not* get this error - just the wrong plaintext. You could use authenticated encryption such as GCM mode encryption to avoid this.